# Departure flight cancelled. Can I ask for a refund of next flights including return flights?

Tags: cancellations, refunds, ryanair

Maybe the title is kind of confusing, you're welcome to make edits if you find it appropriate...

Ryanair pilots have announced a strike for the 20th of December 2017. This day we fly with Ryanair from CRL (Charleroi) to SDR (Santander) for Christmas holidays. With different reservations, we fly on 28th of December from SDR to VLC (Valencia) and on 6th January from ALC (Alicante) back to CRL, both flights with Ryanair as well.

In case my first flight is cancelled, and there is no option for us to go to Spain, do I get a refund for the 2 other flights (different reservations)?

From the Ryanair FAQs:

> How do I apply for a refund?
>
> Refund – Passengers can get a full refund of the price paid for all unused flight sectors within 7 days. **If the disrupted flight is also their outbound sector, customers will be offered a full refund of the return sector**, together with, when relevant, a return flight to the first point of departure at the earliest opportunity (this is for passengers travelling on connecting flights).

It's not clear whether my 2 other reservations are considered as return flights.

I would like to know this in advance just to be prepared on what my rights are.

Comment: Not an answer because I don't know for sure, but generally tickets on separate reservations are not considered return flights. If you had a single multi-city ticket (CRL-SDR-VLC-ALC-CRL or somesuch) the story would likely be different.
You may be able to talk to an agent and get them to make an exception, but I wouldn't count on it.

Comment: This would have to be booked on one ticket in order to have the second and third legs of the trip be refundable.  (I've not used Ryanair, so I'm not sure if they book flights like that, but I have booked such flights with other airlines, i.e. A-B, B-C, C-A.)

Comment: That’s what I think too, but AFAIK there is no combined ticket option when booking with Ryanair.

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness: Have you tried contacting Ryanair customer support? They also have a live chat, which - according to the website - is available 7 days a week, including right now. To enter the chat, you need to provide Name, email and Booking number so I cannot ask on your behalf.

Comment: @Sabine Yes, that's the other option but these days is kind of busy and the queue lasts some time. I've just thought that maybe asking the question here was going to be faster ... I'll try it again

Comment: I would expect everyone else is trying to get their refunds or change their bookings.

Comment: @AlejandroGonzález, can you tell us what happened? Maybe you can write it as an answer and accept it, which will close this question.

Comment: VTC: it's 8 months on, and OP has not added the clarifications or updates requested, making it difficult or impossible to respond.